# Converting a local html file into Uint8List data - Flutter, Dart

Tags: html, flutter, dart

### I need to convert a local HTML file to a Uint8list so it could be printed. Solutions I've found don't seem to work.

### I tried using readAsArrayBuffer but it did not work for me.

```
 void loadImage(html.File file) async {
    final reader = html.FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    await reader.onLoad.first;
    setState(() {
      imageData = reader.result as Uint8List;
    });
  }
```

### the code above requires a Html.file object, I couldn't create one.

Comment: what you want to achieve?
you want to render the html file and then convert it to image like screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do that.

Comment: you got the answer?

Comment: I used the screenshot package, seems to work alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read a local HTML file in Dart outside of a web environment , you can use the dart:io library for file I/O.

```
//Replace 'path/to/your/file.html' with the actual path to your HTML file
String filePath = 'path/to/your/file.html';


// Read the HTML file as a byte list
Future<Uint8List?> readHtmlFile(String filePath) async {
try {
  final File file = File(filePath);
  final Uint8List byteList = await file.readAsBytes();
  return byteList;
} catch (e) {
  print('Error reading HTML file: $e');
  return null;
 }
}

// Usage
readHtmlFile(filePath).then((Uint8List? byteList) {
if (byteList != null) {
  // Do something with the Uint8List
  print('Successfully loaded HTML file as Uint8List: $byteList');
 } else {
  print('Failed to load HTML file.');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package for opening local files.

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['html'],
);

if (result != null) {
  Uint8List fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
  String fileName = result.files.first.name;
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```